# preg_match_all split conditional expression

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have data in this format:

```
Randomtext1(random2, random4) Randomtext2 (ran dom) Randomtext3 Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8) Randomtext5 (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10) Randomtext11()
```

with this:

```
preg_match_all("/\b\w+\b(?:\s*\(.*?\)|)/",$text,$matches);
```

I obtain:

```
0 => 'Randomtext1(random2, random4)',
1 => 'Randomtext2 (ran dom)',
2 => 'Randomtext3',
3 => 'Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)',
4 => 'Randomtext5 (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)',
5 => 'random10',
6 => 'Randomtext11()',
```

but I want

```
0 => 'Randomtext1(random2, random4)',
1 => 'Randomtext2 (ran dom)',
2 => 'Randomtext3',
3 => 'Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)'
4 => 'Randomtext5 (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10)' 
5 => 'Randomtext11()'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be looking to do this over a few lines vs a oneliner regex.  Look for ways to split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive pattern to handle nested parenthesis:

```
if ( preg_match_all('~\w+(?:\s*(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))?~', $text, $matches) )
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eVinpG/1)

details:

```
~    # delimiter
\w+
(?:
    \s*
    ( # capture group 1
        \(
        [^()]*+  # all that isn't a round bracket 
                 # (possessive quantifier *+ to prevent too many backtracking
                 # steps in case of badly formatted string)
        (?:
            (?1) # recursion in the capture group 1
            [^()]*
        )*+
        \)
     )  # close the capture group 1
)? # to make the group optional (instead of "|)")
~
```

Note that you don't need to add word-boundaries around `\w+`

Comment: If I have a lettre with accent, ex: é, the result it's not good. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: @francis: Yes, of course. Use the `u` modifier to extend the `\w` character class to unicode characters.

Comment: Last question, i try with this "intval((#[Météo]#-30)/100) #2572# == 1 || #83# > 0". The result is good but a lost caractere '#' for '#83#'. Thank you for your speed response

Comment: @francis: your question is unclear. This string is out of the scope of the question you asked and has a totally different format. If my answer fits your original question, accept it, and if you want to handle other cases, ask a new question with a clear description of the possible strings with the expected results.

Comment: @francis: other thing, if your goal is to parse a programming language, don't waste your time with regex and look for a parser.

Comment: K, I will post a new question. Thank you.